# Wordpress php - link on a switch button

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i'm stucked on a problem for a couple of hours and i really don't know how to solve it! So, please, i need your help.

I want to edit a wordpress theme. I have this code in the header.php file of the theme

```
    <select id="language-switcher">
        <option value="1">'.esc_html__( 'Română', 'pinar' ).'</option>
            <option value="2">'.esc_html__( 'English', 'pinar' ).'</option>
    </select>
    <!-- End of Language Switcher -->
';
```

And this code is displaying two button from where i cand select two different option(the language) but right now there is no link on them and i want to put one on theme. (see it here - www.hotelperla.ro/english - it's on the right top of the page).
What do i have to write on the php file to make it work? On the english button i want to put this link - www.hotelperla.ro/english and on the romana button www.hotelperla.ro/wp

Thank you a lot!

Comment: does it have to be a link or wouldn't you just use onchange event for the select to redirect ?

Comment: all i want it's to be able to switch betwen links i want to use. it's a multilanguage site and the theme i have, has this button switcher but it's empty and the guy from where i've bought the theme said it will charge me by hour to solve it...LOL

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="language-switcher">
    <option value="http://www.hotelperla.ro/wp">'.esc_html__( 'Română', 'pinar' ).'</option>
    <option value="http://www.hotelperla.ro/english">'.esc_html__( 'English', 'pinar' ).'</option>
</select>

<script>
    document.getElementById('language-switcher').onchange=function() {
        location.href=this.value;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: it's not working. after i've edited the file, i was unable to load the site. Probably fatal error. If i put only the select function it's ok but it's not working, it's the same.

Comment: It works correct.  

I see, that the code you've written in your question is just a piece of output code. I guess, that you've inserted my code as is, but it's wrong way. I can't write the exact full code for your case, if I don't see your full code.  

So, you should manually adapt my code for yours one. You just need to edit your select's value attribute and insert my javascript code after it.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will show you a way to access it:
You can adapt it to match your needs.

> 1st make sure you have jQuery in the head part of your page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, define the function ( `$(document).ready` will make sure there's no attempt to use the select before page is fully loaded, so, no error)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#language-switcher").change(function(){ // listen to action
location.href = this.value; // get the value of the LI and redirect to link/value
});

});
</script>
```

Then the body part :

```
<select id="language-switcher">
<option value="http://www.hotelperla.ro/wp">Română</option>
<option value="http://www.hotelperla.ro/english">English</option>
</select>
```

> reference : [jQuery onchange](https://api.jquery.com/change/)